# Angularjs Select option with multiple static options

Tags: angularjs

I have a select element with `ng-options` to populate options and `<option value="">Select</option>` as a static default option. I want to show another item in options list - `Other`, if selected, renders a `textbox` for user to enter other value. I tried adding another static option with `value="-1"` but it didn't work.

Comment: Why don't you add that option to `ng-options` too? That way, you could watch the model on the select and when it changes to "Other", you then show the textbox using `ng-show`?

Comment: @callmekatootie Yes I thought about it. I'm wondering if there are better way of doing it.

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr of your code so that we can analyze it further?

Answer (score 2):

I would try following:

```
<div ng-init="arr = [{name:'A', val:1},{name:'B', val:2},{name:'C', val:2}]">
  <select ng-model="v">
    <option ng-repeat="o in arr" value="o.val">{{ o.name }}</option>
    <option>Other</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" ng-model="otherval" ng-show="v == 'other'"/>
</div>
```

or,

```
<div ng-init="arr = [{name:'A', val:1},{name:'B', val:2},{name:'C', val:2}]">
  <select ng-model="v" ng-options="o.val as o.name for o in arr.concat([{name:'Other',val:'other'}])">
  </select>
  <input type="number" ng-model="otherval" ng-show="v == 'other'"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I went ahead with adding `Other` option in my options collection. Only downside is that I'll have to validate that if selected value is `other` then discard select model value and take the other input value